# Papers about UX of POS (Points of sale) and Cash management system

Tags: gui-design, user-centered-design, management

For my graduate thesis I have to study the UX of POS and typical cash management system used by restaurants. Do you know if are there any resources available online (or not) about these topics?I don't know where to find some useful resources. I think about Baymard's study about e-commerce sites. Is there something similar about POS and Cash management system?Thank you

Comment: Sorry, but questions requesting recommendations for books / software / apps / papers etc. would fall into the [shopping request](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) category and aren't really suitable to a Q&A website. The reason for this is that there is no one correct answer, and such recommended items would soon be updated and replaced with newer / better versions making the best answers redundant. Therefore you're better off visiting our Chat site for such discussions, they're not really suitable for this main site I'm afraid.

Comment: Start by looking at documentation from POS vendors, such as NCR, Fujitsu, and IBM. Most have somewhat customizable interfaces that may include usability guidelines. Also look at the history of POS UIs, and how it shaped modern POS software.